# how to export a varchar2 from oracledb containing special characters and process it from bash

Tags: oracle, bash, cygwin

I want to export data from an oracledb and then process with a bash script.
However the output may contain special characters (like new-line, etc) which makes it hard to process the plain file.
So I have tried to base64 encode the relevant strings with

```
UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(...))
```

The output file will then contain lines like :

some_text|base64_encoded_string

which gives me easy to process text files however the decoding process doesn't work very well output is gibberish:

```
while read line
do
    name=${line%|*}
    str64=${line#*|}
    str_dec=`echo ${str64} | base64 --decode`
    echo "${name} : ${str_dec}"
done <${export_file}
```

That's probably because the string was first cast to raw in oracle.

So how can I correctly decode the string ?

Alternatively, how can I encode (protect) the string that can be easily decoded, that would help as well ?

btw.: bash is running in cygwin.

Comment: Please see [this question in askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/178521/how-can-i-decode-a-base64-string-from-the-command-line) the base64 should be in the [cygwin coreutils](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86%2Fcoreutils%2Fcoreutils-8.23-4&grep=coreutils)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was pretty simple...
I just had to cast the result back to a varchar2

```
replace(
 replace(
  utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(
   UTL_ENCODE.base64_encode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(...))
  ), chr(10), ''
 ), chr(13), ''
)
```

and it decoded fine, had to remove cr/lf line breaks from the result aswell.